# SQL Query to display 2 columns in correct order

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Check my SQL Query in this Fiddle: [sql fiddle](http://rextester.com/HWASZ21729)

What I want from the SQL Query?

As you can see, I insert 3 things in `recommendations` table.

1. recommendations_tmdb_id
2. recommendations_title
3. recommendations_vote_average

I use `recommendations_tmdb_id` to connect the `recommendations` table to `tmdb_movies table

I want to display `recommendations_title` and `recommendations_vote_average`.

In my original code: This is how i am displaying data:

```
The Dark Knight Rises - 7.5
Batman Begins - 7.5
Iron Man - 7.3
The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King - 8.1
```

etc..

But for the sake of simplicity, i do not want to include full code, just the required code.

So in the SQL fiddle, this is how the data echo

[image]

**Problems with this code:**

Problem number one:

Look at the code carefully. The second `recommendations_vote_average` number is `7.5` and the second `recommendations_title` movie name is `Batman Begins`

So, it means my code shows Batman Begins movie has an vote_average rating of `7.5`, which is false. I insert the rating of Batman Begins as `7.3` not 7.5.

It is showing rating of some other movie. So that means, in wrong order.

Problem number 2:

It shows only 6 `vote_average` results, not 10. I inserted 10 records. 
Why it show only 6 records not 10? Because of `DISTINCT` in my group_concat line.

What if I remove`DISTINCT`? Then, it will show rating of `7.5` to all movies.

So, how do i fix this problem?

**Expected Result:**

```
       recommendations_vote_average                           recommendations_title


7.5, 7.5, 7.3, 8.1, 8, 7.9, 7.9, 8, 6.6, 6.6          The Dark Knight Rises,Batman Begins,Iron Man,The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King,The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring,The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers,The Matrix,Inception,Iron Man 2,Captain America: The First Avenger
```

**SQL Fiddle Full Code**

```
CREATE TABLE tmdb_movies (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmdb_movies (tmdb_id, movie_title) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight');


CREATE TABLE recommendations (
  recommendations_tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  recommendations_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  recommendations_vote_average TEXT NOT NULL
);




INSERT INTO recommendations (recommendations_tmdb_id, recommendations_title, recommendations_vote_average) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight Rises', '7.5'),
(1, 'Batman Begins', '7.5'),
(1, 'Iron Man', '7.3'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '8.1'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring', '8'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '7.9'),
(1, 'The Matrix', '7.9'),
(1, 'Inception', '8'),
(1, 'Iron Man 2', '6.6'),
(1, 'Captain America: The First Avenger', '6.6');


SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
FROM tmdb_movies 

LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=1

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Comment: Drop DISTINCT from aggregation to keep two aggregates aligned

Comment: Then all the records will be same. Example: If the first record is "The Dark Knight Rises" and rating is "7.5", then all 10 records will be the same @Serg

Comment: See the answer, they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop DSTINCT from GROUP_CONCAT()

```
CREATE TABLE tmdb_movies (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmdb_movies (tmdb_id, movie_title) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight');


CREATE TABLE recommendations (
  recommendations_tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  recommendations_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  recommendations_vote_average TEXT NOT NULL
);




INSERT INTO recommendations (recommendations_tmdb_id, recommendations_title, recommendations_vote_average) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight Rises', '7.5'),
(1, 'Batman Begins', '7.5'),
(1, 'Iron Man', '7.3'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '8.1'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring', '8'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '7.9'),
(1, 'The Matrix', '7.9'),
(1, 'Inception', '8'),
(1, 'Iron Man 2', '6.6'),
(1, 'Captain America: The First Avenger', '6.6');


SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average
,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
FROM tmdb_movies ;
```

Returns

```
    movie_title recommendations_vote_average    recommendations_title
1   The Dark Knight 7.5,7.5,7.3,8.1,8,7.9,7.9,8,6.6,6.6 The Dark Knight Rises,Batman Begins,Iron Man,The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King,The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring,The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers,The Matrix,Inception,Iron Man 2,Captain America: The First Avenger
```

http://rextester.com/NNJA85394

Comment: Fixed SQL fiddle link: http://rextester.com/HWASZ21729

Btw did you test the code? If i remove `DISTINCT`, all the data will be same, i.e `7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, ` and `The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, The Dark Knight Rises, `

Comment: Yes, it returns exactly what i've posted in the answer